# Problem in execution of user defined functions in C language

Tags: c, function

I have been developing a c program where I have created the function for a different purpose but few of them are not executing properly i.e. they execute some time and some time not, it just execute the first line where the variable is initialized and after that, it directly jumps to the return section and give the initialized value of the variable even if the condition given is true. Here is the code of the one of the function:

```
int thirdMove()
{
      int r=0;
     if(sq[5]=='0')
     {
        if(sq[1]=='X')
        {
             if(sq[2]=='X' && sq[3]=='0' && sq[7]=='7')
             {
                   r=7;
             }
             else if(sq[2]=='X' && sq[3]=='0' && sq[7]=='X')
             {
                   r=4;
             }
             else if(sq[3]=='X' && sq[2]=='0' && sq[8]=='8')
             {  
                 r=8;
             }
             else if(sq[3]=='X' && sq[2]=='0' && sq[8]=='X')
             {
                    while(1)
                   {
                       r=random();
                       if(r==4 || r==6)
                       {
                          break;
                       }
                       else
                       {
                          continue;
                       }
                    }
             }
             else if(sq[4]=='X' && sq[7]=='0' && sq[3]=='3')
             {
                r=3;
             }
             else if(sq[4]=='X' && sq[7]=='0' && sq[3]=='X')
             {
                r=2;
             }
             else if(sq[6]=='X' && sq[3]=='0' && sq[7]=='7')
             {
                r=7;
             }
             else if(sq[6]=='X' && sq[3]=='0' && sq[7]=='X')
             {
                r=4;
             }
             else if(sq[7]=='X' && sq[3]=='0' && sq[6]=='6')
             {
                r=6;
             }
             else if(sq[7]=='X' && sq[3]=='0' && sq[6]=='X')
             {
                while(1)
                 {
                    r=random();
                    if(r==2 || r==8)
                     {
                         break;
                     }
                    else
                     {
                         continue;
                     }
                 }
             }
             else if(sq[8]=='X' && sq[7]=='0' && sq[3]=='3')
             {
                 r=3;
             }
             else if(sq[8]=='X' && sq[7]=='0' && sq[3]=='X')
             {
                 r=2;
             }
             else if(sq[9]=='X' && sq[2]=='0' && sq[8]=='8')
             {
                 r=8;
             }
             else if(sq[9]=='X' && sq[2]=='0' && sq[8]=='X')
             {
                 r=7;
             }
             else if(sq[9]=='X' && sq[4]=='0' && sq[6]=='6')
             {
                 r=6;
             }
             else if(sq[9]=='X' && sq[4]=='0' && sq[6]=='X')
             {
                 r=3;
             }
             else if(sq[9]=='X' && sq[6]=='0' &&  sq[4]=='4')
             {
                 r=4;
             }
             else if(sq[9]=='X' && sq[6]=='0' &&  sq[4]=='X')
             {
                 r=7;
             }
             else if(sq[9]=='X' && sq[8]=='0' &&  sq[2]=='2')
             {
                  r=2;
             }
             else if(sq[9]=='X' && sq[8]=='0' &&  sq[2]=='X')
             {
                 r=3;
             }
        }   
        else if(sq[2]=='X')
        {
           if(sq[3]=='X' && sq[1]=='0' && sq[9]=='9')
           {
               r=9;
           } 
           else if(sq[3]=='X' && sq[1]=='0' && sq[9]=='X')
           {
               r=6;
           }
           else if(sq[4]=='X' && sq[1]=='0' && sq[9]=='9')
           {
               r=9;
           }
           else if(sq[4]=='X' && sq[1]=='0' && sq[9]=='X')
           {
                 while(1)
                 {
                    r=random();
                    if(r==3 || r==7)
                     {
                         break;
                     }
                    else
                     {
                         continue;
                     }
                 }
           }
           else if(sq[6]=='X' && sq[3]=='0' && sq[7]=='7')
           {
               r=7;
           }
           else if(sq[6]=='X' && sq[3]=='0' && sq[7]=='X')
           {
                 while(1)
                 {
                    r=random();
                    if(r==1 || r==9)
                     {
                         break;
                     }
                    else
                     {
                         continue;
                     }
                 }
           }
           else if(sq[7]=='X' && sq[1]=='0' && sq[9]=='9')
           {
               r=9;
           }
           else if(sq[7]=='X' && sq[1]=='0' && sq[9]=='X')
           {
               r=8;
           }
           else if(sq[8]=='X' && sq[1]=='0' && sq[9]=='9')
           {
               r=9;
           }
           else if(sq[8]=='X' && sq[1]=='0' && sq[9]=='X')
           {
               r=7;
           }
           else if(sq[8]=='X' && sq[3]=='0' && sq[7]=='7')
           {
               r=7;
           }
           else if(sq[8]=='X' && sq[3]=='0' && sq[7]=='X')
           {
                r=9; 
           }
           else if(sq[8]=='X' && sq[7]=='0' && sq[3]=='3')
           {
               r=3;
           }
           else if(sq[8]=='X' && sq[7]=='0' && sq[3]=='X')
           {
               r=1;
           }
           else if(sq[8]=='X' && sq[9]=='0' && sq[1]=='1')
           {
               r=1;
           }
           else if(sq[8]=='X' && sq[9]=='0' && sq[1]=='X')
           {
                r=7; 
           }
           else if(sq[9]=='X' && sq[3]=='0' && sq[7]=='7')
           {
               r=7;
           }
           else if(sq[9]=='X' && sq[3]=='0' && sq[7]=='X')
           {
               r=8;
           }    
        }
        else if(sq[3]=='X')
        {
            if(sq[4]=='X' && sq[1]=='0' && sq[9]=='9')
            {
                r=9;
            }
            else if(sq[4]=='X' && sq[1]=='0' && sq[9]=='X')
            {
                r=6;
            }
            else if(sq[6]=='X' && sq[9]=='0' && sq[1]=='1')
            {
                r=1;
            }
            else if(sq[6]=='X' && sq[9]=='0' && sq[1]=='X')
            {
                r=2;
            }
            else if(sq[7]=='X' && sq[2]=='0' && sq[8]=='8')
            {
                r=8;
            }
            else if(sq[7]=='X' && sq[2]=='0' && sq[8]=='X')
            {
                r=9;
            }
            else if(sq[7]=='X' && sq[4]=='0' && sq[6]=='6')
            {
                r=6;
            }
            else if(sq[7]=='X' && sq[4]=='0' && sq[6]=='X')
            {
                r=9;
            }
            else if(sq[7]=='X' && sq[6]=='0' && sq[4]=='4')
            {
                r=4;
            }
            else if(sq[7]=='X' && sq[6]=='0' && sq[4]=='X')
            {
                r=1;
            }
            else if(sq[7]=='X' && sq[8]=='0' && sq[2]=='2')
            {
                r=2;
            }
            else if(sq[7]=='X' && sq[8]=='0' && sq[2]=='X')
            {
                r=1;
            }
            else if(sq[8]=='X' && sq[9]=='0' && sq[1]=='1')
            {
                r=1;
            }
            else if(sq[8]=='X' && sq[9]=='0' && sq[1]=='X')
            {
                r=2;
            }
            else if(sq[9]=='X' && sq[7]=='0' && sq[4]=='4')
            {
                r=4;
            }
            else if(sq[9]=='X' && sq[7]=='0' && sq[4]=='X')
            {
                 while(1)
                 {
                    r=random();
                    if(r==2 || r==8)
                     {
                         break;
                     }
                    else
                     {
                         continue;
                     }
                 }
            }
        }
        else if(sq[4]=='X')
        {

        }
     }
     else if(sq[5]=='X')
     {

     }
   return r;
}
```

In this function, it has to execute some conditions if they are true then it should return the value according to the condition but it only returns 0 which is assigned to the variable r.
While debugging the function it terminates at `int r=0;`
and returns the wrong value even if the conditions are true. 
Similarly, I have two more functions with the same type of operations and they are causing the same problem.
Please help me to resolve this problem and please simplify your suggestions or solutions for a better understanding for me as I am a beginner.
Thank You

Comment: For `char* sq="ooooooo";` the function for example correctly drops through to return. What makes you think it should not? What is the content of `sq` which makes you expect a different behaviour. In short, please make a [mre].

Comment: It seems that none of your copious conditions has caught. Have you tried printing all values in question when you enter thiis function or examining them in a debugger?

Comment: Try inserting an `else {/* no condition was met */ }` just before the `return`, also a good place to output `sq`. As M Oehm has proposed.

Comment: This problem would be easier for you and others to solve if you simplified it. Can you make a shorter program that still has the same problem?

Comment: To randomly choose one of two numbers: `if (random()%2) r=2; else r=8;`

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the purpose of this function. What is its purpose?

Comment: @ruralcoder: To determine where to place the next 0 in a game of noughts and crosses.